# Androidx fontscale not working on HuaWei Mate20

Tags: android, androidx, huawei-mobile-services

I am using Androidx 1.1.0, when i override the "getResources()" function in my "AppCompatActivity" when i set the fontscale to 1.5f in the "getResources()" function, it does not work. And i change the androidx library to support library it works fine. Anyone get the same problem ?

Answer (score 0):

First step open Huawei mate20 and click system settings
Second step, after entering the mobile phone system setting interface,click display.
Third step,after entering the display interface,click font and display size.
Step four, after entering the font and display size interface, you can see that adjusting the font size only adjust the font,display size adjusts the font,picture and other interface elements.
 Step 5,here,adust the font size, and the display size can be set as required.